# Creating list with the same number of values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set with a date, ID, and coordinates that I would like to split into seasonal months. For example for winter I have January to `winter1`, February to `winter2`, and March to `winter3`. I have done the same for the summer months.

I would like to filter out the IDs that have all of these months, so that when I split the data by ID and year, I would have identical list lengths.

I wasn't sure how to simulate uneven values for each ID in the sample code below, but in my actual data some IDs only have `summer1` and not `winter1`, while it could be flipped around for `summer2` and winter2`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(season_categ = case_when(month %in% 6 ~ 'summer1',
                                  month %in% 7 ~ 'summer2',
                                  month %in% 8 ~ 'summer3',
                                  month %in% 1 ~ 'winter1',
                                  month %in% 2 ~ 'winter2',
                                  month %in% 3 ~ 'winter3')) %>%
  group_by(year, ID )%>% 
  filter(any(month %in% 6:8) &
           any(month %in% 1:3))

summer_list <- df1 %>% 
  filter(season_categ == "summer1") %>% 
  group_split(year, ID)

# Renames the names in the list to AnimalID and year
names(summer_list) <- sapply(summer_list, 
                             function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
                                               x$year[1], sep = '_'))

# Creates a list for each year and by ID
winter_list <- df1 %>% 
  filter(season_categ == "winter1") %>% 
  group_split(year, ID)

names(winter_list) <- sapply(winter_list, 
                             function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
                                               x$year[1], sep = '_'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want, but I understood that you would want to get rid of IDs that have less than the 6 months of Q1 and Q3 in any of the years, but you could modify the filter or grouping if that assumption was wrong.

Here is one approach:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)

# random sampling of dates with this seed gives no July date for ID 2 in 2010
df <- tibble(
  date = sample(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 
  1000, replace = TRUE), 
  x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
  ID = rep(1:5, 200),
  month = month(date),
  year  =year(date)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, date)

df %>%
  filter(month %in% c(1:3, 6:8)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  mutate(complete = length(unique(month)) == 6) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(all(complete)) %>%
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it is not really clear as to what your are looking for.  Before you split the data into a list sort the rows by columns

```
df1<-df1[order(ID,season_categ),]

### Determine which ID's have uneven numbers ###
df1 %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarize(month_seq = paste(season_categ , collapse = "_"),
          number_of_months = n(season_categ))

#### Remove odd numbers###
```

Comment: I think essentially I would like to identify the individuals in my data set with all of the 6 of the months that I had indicated. I'm also getting an error with the last line of code ```Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `number_of_months`.
x unused argument (season_categ)
i Input `number_of_months` is `n(season_categ)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: ID = 1.```.